# How update existing IOS app with expo app in testFight and app store

Tags: react-native, expo, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

I need to update existing IOS app with expo app and I need some documentations or ways.

I can successfully connect app-store-connect with expo app and connect TestFlight

Comment: the question needs more details....

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.